# Can someone explain this behavior in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I created a list called a, when I inserted a at the beginning of the list this happened

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> a.insert(0, a)
>>> a
[[...], 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: You've inserted a reference to `a` as the first element of `a`. What don't you understand?

Comment: `a` is a list. What did you expect to happen by inserting a list?

Comment: It's just the way Python displays a circular reference. If it didn't, then you'd have infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Running this code:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a.insert(0, a)
print(a)
print(a[0])
```

yields this result:

```
[[...], 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
[[...], 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

this leads me to believe this is how python handles printing recursive referencing. `a` contains a reference to `a`, which contains a reference to `a`... meaning there's no good way to actually print it, so it just prints `[...]`

---

if you want to include the values of `a` inside of a pointer to `a`, you might want to copy it

this code:

```
import copy
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a.insert(0, copy.deepcopy(a))
print(a)
```

results in this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

[...] stands for the list itself that you previously added.